# Expiring date for content wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-expiration

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-timed-plugin/

Im using this function to dissapear(not delete) expired posts:

```
<?php if (function_exists('simple_timed_content')) : ?>
<?php if (simple_timed_content("offdate=20120309 offtime=2350")) : ?> 
 Some content goes here 
<?php endif; ?> <?php endif; ?>
```

I want to use as dates from custom fields like this:

```
 <?php if (simple_timed_content("offdate='$end_date' offtime='$end_time'")) : ?>
```

where : `

```
$end_date=date( 'Ymd', strtotime( get_post_meta( $Post->ID, "_EventEndDate", true),     time()));`
```

and

```
$end_time=date( 'HM', strtotime( get_post_meta( $Post->ID, "_EventEndDate", true), time()));`
```

Assuming allways that _EventEndDate value is : Ymd HM (20120309 2350)
How would be the complete code for this to work?

My other option is to use this code i found :

**www.rockia.com/2010/01/modify-you-wordpress-theme-to-enable-an-expiration-for-your-posting**

but it doesnt seem to work with my

**www.wordpress.org/extend/themes/bombax**

where loop is in single.php file

If someone could help I would appreciate it. Im new to php.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have different way to accomplish this try below

Edit your theme and replace your current WordPress loop by this "hacked" loop:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
     while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
         $disappeartime = get_post_custom_values('disappear');
         if (is_array($disappeartime)) {
             $disappearstring = implode($disappeartime);
         }

         $secondsbetween = strtotime($disappearstring)-time();
         if ( $secondsbetween > 0 ) {
             // For exemple...
             the_title();
             the_excerpt();
         }
     endwhile;
endif;
?>
```

To create a post with date/time **disappear**, just create a custom field. Give it **disappear** as a key and your date/time **(format: mm/dd/yyyy 00:00:00)** as a value.
The post will not show after that time stamp.

Comment: I know this hack , i couldnt make it work in my theme . The code in www.rockia.com makes the post not just to disappear but it also deletes the post. My theme is little strange or i could say simlpier and the loop is in single.php. is this:

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/bombax-theme/source/browse/trunk/single.php?r=35   The only thing that worked so far was the above plugin but i have to get values from custom fields

Comment: i used content scheduler plugin and ''_cs-expire-date'' is the name of key and the value  its been inserted automatically. And preset the  checkbox to enabled for all my posts in the plgugins file